# What's the definition of "not now" for priority-of-b'racha purposes?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements, eating, priorities

*Orach Chayim* 211 is about what food to recite a blessing over (that is, and eat) first when one wishes to eat two foods. It's clear that (except according to the *Rambam* cited in 211:2) one does not always eat first the food he wishes to eat first. (*Mishna B'rura* :13 rules that we don't follow that holding of the *Rambam*'s.)

However, the *Rama* :5 adds an important caveat to the general rule:

> And all we've said, that one [food] precedes another, is specifically when he wishes to eat from both of them…. However, if he doesn't wish to eat from both of them, he recites the blessing over [and eats] only the one he wants to eat, even though the other is also placed before him.

It seems obvious (and I believe, though I don't have them handy, that this is clarified in latter-day *hilchos b'rachos* books) that the *Rama*'s exception applies not only to someone who wants to eat only one food altogether, but also to someone who wants to eat only one food *now*. That is, if dessert and my main course are both on the table, I need not eat dessert first, even if it should in theory have priority.

These two details are opposing forces in the *halacha*. On the one hand, one cannot decide what to eat first: *halacha* dictates what to eat first. On the other, the *halacha* is overridden by his lack of desire to eat something immediately: in a sense, he *can* decide what to eat first.

What's the demarcation? To what extent does the *Rama*'s exception hold, and when do we say "that's not enough of a not-wanting-to-eat-it-now to override the general *halacha*"?

Comment: Extremely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30400

Comment: @WAF a duplicate, you think?

Comment: I would guess that answers to this would differ from answers to that, and the answer there that provides a source is part of the question here, so I'm inclined towards it not being a duplicate.