# Bracha on coffee before pastry

Tags: mezonot-beracha, shehakol-beracha

If one sits down to eat mezonos and drink coffee and the person truly does not want to eat the mezonos for a period of time (just to sip the coffee), is it permissible to make the bracha shehakol first (on the coffee) and mezonos later (on the pastry). Would it make sense to cover the pastry like we cover challah on Shabbos for kiddush?

Comment: What if one wants to drink water in the field. Must he first pick an apple to eat and eat since it's HaEtz?

Comment: Why do you think it’s a problem to make the Shehakol first, provided you have in mind that it shouldn’t cover the pastry? What does covering the Challah have anything to do with anything?

Comment: I don't think that you get penalized for changing your mind. Seems that perhaps a more practical question is if the purpose of eating the cake is to get the bitter taste out of the coffee rather than getting *hana'ah* from the cake. (That's imilar to the idea of eating kichel to get the saltiness out of the herring.)

Comment: The kedima for berachot apply only if you want to eat them together

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48527/170 or of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30400/170